# py2app successful, but app crashes beyond login "bcrypt" password check window

Tags: python, bcrypt, py2app, passlib

This project here: https://github.com/patarapolw/HosPy

`setup.py` is as follows

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['HosPy']
DATA_FILES = [
    ('database',['database/login.db'])
]
OPTIONS = {
    'includes': ['cffi'],
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'HosPy'
    }
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app','PyQt5','bcrypt','cffi'],
)
```

I can run the app, but I can't go beyond the login window. At first, I can't login at all, but now I can partially...

I figured that I have to open into the content and manually move `login.db` into `database/`.

Now, wrong username is OK, but when correct username but wrong password: cannot find bcrypt backend...

Yay, successfully created via `setup.py` alone, by changing `from passlib.hash import bcrypt` to `import bcrypt`; and `'includes': ['cffi']`.